# Screen compatibility on android devices

Tags: android, android-manifest

I would like to let download my app just for smartphone and not for tablet.

In the manifest i have put this lines for screen compatibility

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all large size screens --> 
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

in Normal size screen, i have add a line with screen density = 480. This should let devices such samsung s5 able to download the app.

Surfing the web, i found that to avoid the app be downloadable from tablets, i should remove the part dedicate to screens xlarge.
But if i do so, i am afraid that then, devices such samsung s4 and samsung s5, will be not able to download my app.

It s true?

Answer (score 3):

Well, let's see.
You can refer to this link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

To know what sizes mean what "screenSize" or screenDensity, more specifically, this image.

[image]

So the Samsung S5 for example has a 5.1 inch display, which by that graph is large; and a density of 432 ppi which means xhdpi (well it's considered something like xxhdpi isn't it?). 
Why have you added it to normal? The size should be large (unless the hardware is giving incorrect readings to the OS, not unheard of, unlikely for Samsung devices though).

Either way, removing what they said would look like

```
    <compatible-screens>
<!-- all small size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
<!-- all normal size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
<!-- all large size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
```

Leaving the s8 unaffected.

It is never easy, nor really possible considering how many devices following odd rules there are running android (earlier versions of android didn't even follow these exact rules), to block just tablets. Yes we all wish they came up with a simple Tablet tag.

Leaving large in means some tablets will be able to install your app (there are 7inch tablets). Taking large out means most phablets and even flagship phones get the cut.

In the end, what you should focus on is, blocking not by what the devices definition is, but by how your app looks on that size. Hope this helps.

edit: This wiki link is also pretty usefull [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So do you think i should change <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" /> with <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" /> and remove all the large screen size section?

Answer (score 1):

The s4 will be able to download the app for this line:

```
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
```

Please check:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=39622

and this doc:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHansetApps
In "Declaring an App is Only for Handsets"

Comment: @Bombolo Yes. The S5 and S4 displays densities fall in the same bucket.